# Filter timestamp column by hours

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, timestamp

I have a dataframe:

```
ID           time
1      2018-04-04 07:04:56
2      2018-04-04 09:14:56
3      2018-04-04 21:45:11
4      2018-04-05 18:14:26
5      2018-04-05 19:45:54
6      2018-04-05 19:47:01
7      2018-04-05 19:49:58
8      2018-04-05 21:05:10
```

I want to filter "time" for each day and remove rows if they are not interval from 8am to 21pm. So desired result must look like this:

```
ID           time
2      2018-04-04 09:14:56
4      2018-04-05 18:14:26
5      2018-04-05 19:45:54
6      2018-04-05 19:47:01
7      2018-04-05 19:49:58
```

How could i do that? I don't get how to di that, if my timestamp includes days and months and years, not only hours

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use [pandas.DateTimeIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", delimiter=";") # your CSV/DataFrame/whatever
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
print(df[(df.time.dt.hour > 8) & (df.time.dt.hour < 21)])
```

Make sure that the time column is in datetime format with `df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time)`